# Power automate "when a HTTP request is recevied" trigger. How to get file attachment

Tags: c#, power-automate

So I have this flow where you pass an email address and attachment. I have no issues getting the email address but for the attachment I am not sure how to do it.

I dont know what JSON schema that I need to receive or get the file attachment.

Basically, when I receive the file, I need to send an email to a customer and attach that file.

[image]

As for c# side, here's what im doing (before attachments):

```
 var myObject = new
        {
            name = req.Name,
            emailAddress = req.Email
        };

        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await http.PostAsJsonAsync("https://xx.xx.com", myObject);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Ok
            }
        }
```

Here's im planning to with attachments:

```
  using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var values = new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("emailAddress", req.Email),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("emailAttachment", req.EmailAttachment)                    };

                foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
                {
                    multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value),
                        String.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
                }

                string path = @"C:\BMW.pdf";  // TODO: create from memory
                multipartFormDataContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(path)),
                    '"' + "emailAttachment" + '"',
                    '"' + "BMW.pdf" + '"');

                var requestUri = "https://xxxx.xxxxx.com";
                var result = await http.PostAsync(requestUri, multipartFormDataContent);
            }
```

flow

[image]

Comment: You need to encode your attachment as a base64 string and send it over http to LogicApps that way.

Answer (score 0):

**The below code helped me to send an email attaching the document :**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public void email_send()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"); // your smtp provider
    mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Subject comes here";
    mail.Body = "Email body content here";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt"); // Url of the attaching file url
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587; // Smtp port 
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);

}
```

Comment: thank you but this is not what I need. the email sending functionality is already working.